# Best way to create JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Which is the best way to create a `JFrame` and handle it?

1. Create a class and inside it create an object `JFrame`
2. Inherit from `JFrame` like `class MyClass extends JFrame`

Comment: what does the performance mean ?

Comment: Note to all who will wonder about mentioning "performance" in comments and answers: the original title of this question was "Best way to create JFrame in terms of performance" :)

Comment: I'm mean 'performance' the best way for a programmer without encouring in error

Comment: Create a million JFrames this way - measure. Create a million JFrames that way - measure. Tell us.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whenever possible, do not use inheritance (your class **is-a** JFrame) but choose composition (e.g. your class **has-a** JFrame). It's a common design principle.

And it doesn't have any significant impact on performance.

Comment: so whick could be the best way, not to inherit from JFrame, right?

Comment: In what way this approach influences on performance?

Comment: In this case I think it's a good way for structuring the code in components, let the class inherit JFrame and implement it's functionally within the class.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, the only times you should extend JFrame is if you need to overload any methods in it.

That being said, there shouldn't be any noticeable performance hit one way or the other.